# Where these .js file come to source code?

Tags: plugins, php

on my blog in source code there are 3 Javascript also jquery file. It comes from `wp-include`  but from where are them loaded? Can i not combined them in one file?
My source: [view-source:liebeundsprueche.com](http://view-source:liebeundsprueche.com)

I mean about these 3 Jquery file:

```
liebeundsprueche.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.12.4
liebeundsprueche.com/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.1
liebeundsprueche.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1
```

Can not i combine them? And make one file?

Comment: combining js files make the browser to take longer to finish loading of the page, which means that for a longer time your user might not be able to use JS related functionality. Why would you want that?

Comment: @MarkKaplun How would one request take longer than three separate sequential requests?

Comment: `wp_head` load these files for you

Comment: where can i find it?

Comment: browsers load 17 files at the same time.if you need to load 17 equal size JS files. it will take about 17 times longer if you try to create one file out of them. This is obviously a "lab environment" math,and there are other factors in play but the point is that it is actually not a common sense thing at all that serving one file instead of 3 will make your site faster

Answer (score 0):

they're [`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) scripts.

You can remove them (if you're positive nothing uses them) with [`wp_dequeue_script()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) similar to the following:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
   wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
   wp_deregister_script( 'wp-embed' );
}, 99 );
```

or with

```
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', function(&$scripts){
    if(!is_admin()) {
        $scripts->remove( 'jquery' );
        $scripts->remove( 'wp-embed' );
    }
} );
```

Comment: These two codes are similar? should i add one of them in function.php at the bottom?